# AMPscript: Using date in LookupOrderedRows is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, date

I would like to use date LookupOrderedRows()

My code:

```
SET @DetailRows = LookupOrderedRows("ST_Import_date", 1, "ID ASC", "Import_Date", Format(now(),"MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

When I try to get the rows with respect to current date, I am not getting matching rows(row count is 0). but the DE does contains today's date.

Could you please help me if I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Dates in SFMC are stored with the time (e.g. [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)). In order to retrieve a row, you'll need to know the time portion also.  All of the AMPScript lookup functions require an exact match.

Another option is to use API filter with AMPScript.  It's a little more involved, but it allows you to use more operators.

[AMPScript InvokeRetrieve](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/#InvokeRetrieve)

You'd want to use the `DataExtensionObject[DECustomerKey]` Object to pull from a Data Extension.  Partial example can be found [in this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/111048/5202).

Answer (score 0):

When you do the Lookup with just the "Date" value (MM/dd/yyyy), the SFMC assumes the time to be "12 AM". Hence it will look for the same exact date with time as 12AM.